# Javascript - Add an object into an array if it's not already there otherwise, increase the quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I want to add objects into a local storage array if they are not in it otherwise, increase the objects' quantity by 1. Here is my function:

```
function addToCart() {
    let productsTable = localStorage.getItem("productList");

    // Check if productsTable exists in local storage
    if (productsTable === null){

        // If not, initialize the array and add the current object
         productsTable = [];
         objetProduit.quantity ++;
         productsTable.push(objetProduit);
    }else{

        // If yes, decode the array. 
        productsTable = JSON.parse(productsTable);

        // check if the object is already in the array
        if(productsTable.find(product => product.id !== objetProduit.id)){
            
        //if not ==> add the object into the array
            objetProduit.quantity ++;
            productsTable.push(objetProduit);
        }else if (productsTable.find(product => product.id == objetProduit.id)){

            //if yes ==> just increase the value of the key quantity by 1
            objetProduit.quantity ++;
        }
    }
    // Encode the array.
    productsTable = JSON.stringify(productsTable);

    // Add the array back to LocalStorage. 
    localStorage.setItem("productList", productsTable);
```

The objetcs are instances of the class below :

```
class Appareil {
    constructor(id,name,price,description,imageURL, quantity){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }
}
```

The array get initialized but items are not added in it nor is the quantity modified.

Comment: Using a different variable for the JSON and the array adds significant clarity. After that, replace the if/else with a simple if and treat all cases the same. Also change the inner else-if to an else (don’t do: if x else if !x..). Then the entire problem can be reduced (eg. refined) to either the serialization or the handling of the array - right now it’s just a “debug this code” without any reduction to a minimal case.

Comment: `objetProduit.quantity ++`; - I think you shouldn't put a  space before ++
`objetProduit.quantity++` or `++objetProduit.quantity`

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it  and removed the space and it's the same result.

Comment: productsTable.find(product => product.id !== objetProduit.id) — that is bad logic, regardless of anything else; it will find _all_ non-related products and can’t be used to determine if the item exists in the array or not. Only use the positive-find form here, and see above about removing the else-if: if(!..find(..==..)) // not found

Comment: Sorry If these questions are unnecessary due to my inexpertise, but shouldn't function addToCart() be a method inside a class? If not, perhaps objetProduit could be an argument of a function passed by reference, in the second case, there could be this.objetProduit. I've no idea if it solves anything or is correct reasoning, but I hope it helps a bit... I might delete this comment if it doesn't.

Comment: So you are pushing a reference to an ES6 class instance to an array and then you JSON.stringify it to store it in localStorage? I would not store class instances in localstorage but just plain objects (or just give the classes a 'toObject' method would do it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the following check condition:

```
if(productsTable.find(product => product.id !== objetProduit.id))
```

as it will return the first product's index which doesn't match in the array, so chances are there will be many products which will not be matching

Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Try:

```
function addToCart() {
    let productsTable = localStorage.getItem("productList");

    // Check if productsTable exists in local storage
    if (!productsTable) {

        // If not, initialize the array and add the current object
        productsTable = [];
        objetProduit.quantity++;
        productsTable.push(objetProduit);
    } else {

        // If yes, decode the array. 
        productsTable = JSON.parse(productsTable);

        // check if the object is already in the array
        if (productsTable.find(product => product.id === objetProduit.id)) {

            //if yes ==> just increase the value of the key quantity by 1
            objetProduit.quantity++;
            for (var i = 0; i < productsTable.length; i++) {
                if (objetProduit.id === productsTable[i].id) { //look for match with id
                    productsTable[i].quantity++; //add
                    break; //exit loop
                }
            }
        } else {
            //if not ==> add the object into the array
            objetProduit.quantity++;
            productsTable.push(objetProduit);

        }
    }
    // Encode the array.
    productsTable = JSON.stringify(productsTable);

    // Add the array back to LocalStorage. 
    localStorage.setItem("productList", productsTable);
}
```